# why i'm getting this error ::Expected response to be a <2XX: success>, but was a <302: Found> redirect to <http://www.example.com/users/sign_in>

Tags: ruby-on-rails, session, devise, minitest

`` After running `RAILS_ENV=test rails test test/controllers ``  i'm getting

`Expected response to be a <2XX: success>, but was a <302: Found>redirect to <http://www.example.com/users/sign_in>`

Response body:You are being [redirected](http://www.example.com/users/sign_in).

======================

```
class OpeningsControllerTest < ActionDispatch::IntegrationTest

  test "should get new" do
    get new_opening_url
    assert_response :success
  end
end**
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you set current_user while running test cases? if you did not assign the current user then use [this](https://gist.github.com/jwo/7323240) reference to assign current user before all action in the test case.

Because if you are used the authenticated a user in the application controller or used the devise then this method is required to authenticate a user or admin user and If the current user not found then it is redirecting to user_sign_in_path.

Comment: yes i already set current_user in test_helper.rb still i'm getting this error, i guess i need to sign_in first then this will work but i don't know how to do that ,will you help me?

Answer (score 0):

Try something like :

```
`
class OpeningsControllerTest < ActionDispatch::IntegrationTest

  test "should get new" do
    sign_in users(:rathod)
    get new_opening_url
    assert_response :success
  end
end**
`
```

This means you need to create a user in a fixture file: users.yml

```
rathod:
  email: "JEVBR@test.com"
  first_name: "rathod"
  last_name: "bar"
```

Guess you are using Devise, so you need the test-helpers of device to get access to the "sign_in" helper